# Google Maps Api find only province

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm currently in a fight with the Google Maps API.

For example, San José in Costa Rica.
There is a city called 'San José' and a province 'San José'. I need to find the province. So I use this request:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=**San José Province**&components=country:CR&language=nl](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=San%20Jos%C3%A9%20Province&components=country:CR)

You would think this should return the province San José, but it doesn't. It returns the city.

```
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
```

When I search for:
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=San Jos**e** Province&components=country:CR&language=nl](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=San%20Jose%20Province&components=country:CR&language=nl)
(only difference is an *e* instead of an *é* in Jose)
it does return the province.

```
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
```

But of course this is being used grammatically and the input is "san josé". 
**How can I get only results of provinces? (administrative_area 's)**

Answer (score 0):

You also get the `administrative_area_level_1` result if you query for "Province of San José":

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Province%20of%20San%20Jos%C3%A9&components=country:CR

This may work differently across different countries think. I'd venture this form (Province of ...) is more common ─and likely to get the right results─ in Spanish speaking countries.